# Twilio Conversation API Sample code with .NET, JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, twilio, chat

I am looking for sample code for Twilio chat (Conversation API) not programmable chat with the use of .NET, JavaScript, jQuery (Not react or node).

I talked with Twilio support team but they don't have any sample of it.

Your help would be appreciated if you have or just give me hint from where I can implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not a fully built example of a Twilio Conversations API application built in .NET with JQuery. However, there is plenty of documentation on this.

The [Conversations API Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart?code-sample=code-create-your-first-conversation&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x) walks you through making requests to the Conversations REST API to create conversations and participants. And it provides a prebuilt UI that you can then use to interact with the conversation.

While Twilio Chat is being sunset soon, it works quite similarly to Conversations, so this guide on [Chat with C# and ASP.NET MVC](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-csharp-mvc) would still be useful to walkthrough. This [application's front-end](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/twiliochat-csharp) is written with JQuery too.

Other than that, you should find it useful to read through [the guides on Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/fundamentals) as well as the guides on [how to use the SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/initializing-conversations-sdk-clients). Finally, [the JS SDK docs](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/2.1.0/docs/) are also very useful for finding all the events that different objects fire and their available methods.

Comment: Having a real sample would go a long way to convince people to use Twilio Conversations in web sites. 

Just browsing around at the options out there, I found one (Tawk.to) which allows you to drop in a JavaScript reference and instantly have chat capabilities. The ease of integration is highly enticing.

Comment: It sounds like you want something simpler than Twilio. Twilio allows for a completely custom experience, whereas a drop in system is easier to implement, but gives you less control. All things to weigh up as you make a decision. There are also Conversations samples, just not one that combines jQuery and .NET.